# bootstrap timepicker change event

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to self learn angular 8. Making a jump from angularjs. I always find date and time pickers to to most intimidating part of coding. I have been pretty successful in creating a beautiful reactive form in angular 8.
As always i get stuck in date and time.
So i was using input type date and time it was working perfectly in chrome and in IE not at all.
Went researching bootstrap for rescue and came up with this

```
<div class="input-group col-md-6">  
   <div class="input-group-prepend col-md-6" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <label class="input-group-text w-100">Reviewers Arrival Time</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-control" style="height:auto !important;" 
   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.mealSerStartTimeRev.errors, 
   'col-md-4': submitted && f.mealSerStartTimeRev.errors}">
       <ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="timeStart" formControlName="mealSerStartTimeRev" 
          show-spinners="false" [meridian]="true" (ngModelChange)="onTimeChange($event)">
       </ngb-timepicker>    
    </div>
```

This is working fine the ngModelChange works well with ngModel and since my form is reactive i have formcontrolname for validation getting form value etc
Now the issue I am having is I am getting a warning

```
It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
in Angular v7.

For more information on this, see our API docs here:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel
```

I understood the message cannot use ngmodel with formcontrolNAme. So how will i manage the change event. I need the change event. Lot of business logic happens in change event. any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please tell why are you using ngModel at the first place ?

Are you using ngModel just to use ngModelChange ?

Comment: Yes. All I want is the (change) event. regular (change) = "onTimeChange($event)" does not work

Comment: Please let me furnish a answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the valueChanges available like ::

```
 this.formGroupName.get('mealSerStartTimeRev').valueChanges.subscribe(x => 
--- Logic goes here ----
);
```

or,

```
 this.formGroupName.controls.mealSerStartTimeRev.valueChanges.subscribe(x => 
--- Logic goes here ----
);
```

Either is fine.

Comment: will i have to make object observable then add these in line in  constructor or ngOnInit. I was reading on it. i was not very successful. My page load data with get operation was made observable then changed the value but breakpoint did not hit the code

Comment: No need to make any observable.  The form group which you created with controls has a valueChanges property which is an observable. You will just need to consume it. It observes changes and fires an event to observer internally

Comment: please bear with me i am not sure i understand this completely. my form this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        mealSerStartTimeRev: [this.timeStart, [Validators.required]],
        mealSerEndTimeRev: [this.timeEnd, [Validators.required]],
      }); It is in  ngOninit funtion. Where do i put  this.dynamicform.controls.mealSerStartTimeRev.valueChanges.subscribe(x => 
--- Logic goes here ----
); for break point to recognise the change(or change event to fire)

Comment: You can subscribe just after creating the form group inside ngOnInit itself

Comment: The code block gets executed only when there's value change in that form control so don't worry about placing it in onInit. There will be no performance hit.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Dhanyawad

Comment: No problem buddy !